# C# ReadLine float

Tags: c#, input, console.readline

I try convert string to float because I using `Console.ReadLine()` for input.

The `Console.ReadLine()` only accept string values, but I need convert. How I can do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        float val = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(val);
```

OR

```
        float val2;
        if (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out val2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not a valid float");
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine(val2);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Convert.ToDouble()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3x7f55(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert the entered string value

```
double input = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use float.TryParse. It should look someone like this.

```
float fl;
float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out fl);
```

Although that should work, you can also put use the tryparse in an if statement so that there will be an alert if it does not parse. Like this:

```
float fl;
if(!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out fl)){
Console.WriteLine("It didn't parse");
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: In your first sentence, you say `Console.TryParse`, but your code shows that you meant `float.TryParse`

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I didn't realize that I messed that up.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `double.TryParse` in the`do..while` loop in order to keep asking until correct value is entered:

```
 double input = 0.0;

 do { 
   Console.WriteLine("Please enter floating point value");
 }
 while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string  User_Text  = Console.ReadLine();
float   User_Float = Convert.ToSingle(User_Text);
```

This was initially my own question... and this is the answer I found!